# Question regarding convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If the series with general term $a_n^2$ converges, why does the series with general term $a_n/n$ converge as well??? A peer of mine showed me this, but I really don't find it obvious and I really don't know how to prove it..

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Cauchy-Schwarz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) says
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|a_n|}{n}\le\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\right)^{1/2}
$$
so the series is [absolutely convergent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence).

Comment: Absolute being the mathematical term and not robjohn being certain.

Comment: @Alizter: absolutely!

Answer (score 2):

If $a_{n} \geq 0$, (as in the Rudin exercise $\sum a_{n}$ converges $\Rightarrow$ $\sum \sqrt{a_{n}}/n$ converges), we have the following:

If $\sum a_{n}^{2}$ converges, then $\sum \left(a_{n}^{2} + \frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)$ also converges.  But
$$0 \leq \left(a_{n} - \frac{1}{n}\right)^{2} = a_{n}^{2} + \frac{1}{n^{2}} - 2\frac{a_{n}}{n},$$
so
$$\frac{a_{n}}{n} \leq \frac{1}{2}\left(a_{n}^{2} + \frac{1}{n^{2}}\right).$$
Thus, $\sum \frac{a_{n}}{n}$ converges.

Comment: You need some absolute values.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Where do I need absolute values at?

Comment: You've essentially reproven Cauchy-Schwarz

Comment: You need lower bounds as well as upper to show the sum converges.

Comment: @robjohn This was intentional since I believe this is based on a Rudin exercise and I don't believe he does Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Indeed.  I was assuming positive terms.